# Microbial Fuel Cell Reaction

Tags: homework

I found a formula online which explained the reaction which occurred in the anode chamber of a microbial fuel cell but there was a typo

$\small NADH + Ferredoxin_{(ox)} (NADH-Ferredoxin\ Oxidoreductase) \longrightarrow NAD^+ + Ferredoxin_{(red)}\ \
Ferredoxin_{(red)} (Hydrogenase)\#61614;Ferredoxin_{(ox)} + 2H^+ + 2e^-$

I attempted to correct it but I'm not sure if I'm right could you check this and see if it's correct?

$\small NADH-Ferredoxin\ Oxidoreductase \longrightarrow NAD^+ + Ferredoxin_{(red)}$

$\small Ferredoxin_{(red)} \longrightarrow Hydrogenase + Ferredoxin_{(ox)} + 2H^+ + 2e^-$

Comment: This the page? http://www.altenergymag.com/emagazine.php?issue_number=07.04.01&article=haldia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Anode reaction,

$\small Glucose + 2NAD^+ (Embden-Meyerhof pathway) \leftrightharpoons 2 Pyruvate + 2NADH$

$\small Pyruvate + Ferredoxin_{(ox)} (Pyruvate-ferredoxin Oxidoreductase) \leftrightharpoons Acetyl-CoA + CO_2 + Ferredoxin_{(red)}$

$\small NADH + Ferredoxin _{(ox)} (NADH-Ferredoxin Oxidoreductase) \leftrightharpoons NAD^+ + Ferredoxin_{(red)}$

$Ferredoxin_{(red)} (Hydrogenase)\leftrightharpoons Ferredoxin_{(ox)} + 2H^+ + 2e^-$

[Last one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferredoxin_hydrogenase]

### Cathode reaction,

$4 H^+  + 4e^- + O_2 \leftrightharpoons H_2O$

$C_6H_{12}O_6 + 6O_2 \leftrightharpoons 6 CO_2 + 6 H_2O, DG° = - 2870 kj$

Full paper: http://www.altenergymag.com/emagazine.php?issue_number=07.04.01&article=haldia